# How to resume an exited app in Android Wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am recognizing gestures using android wearable watch and android smartphone. Gestures performed by the hand wearing the watch are recognized and sent to smartphone via messageapi to display the same.

Now I have a start and stop button in wearable app to enable and disable the sensor listener(accelerometer, gyro sensors etc). I believe when you swipe left to right, a wearable app is exited. When I exit after clicking the stop button, I don't recognize anything when I do the same set of actions - quite normal.

But when I don't press the stop button and exits the app and performs the given gestures, my phone is able to recognize them. And if I open the wearable app again, I can see the start button again. But still smart phone recognizes the gestures performed. And if I click the start button and performs some gestures, my phone shows two gestures one after the other(the first and second sessions of app). I am not sure how this is happening.

I would like to know what happens when we swipe left to right to a wearable app? Can I go back to the same session if I swipe left to tight? Is there any other way to kill the app?

Could anyone throw some light on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

What happens is somewhat similar to pressing the "home" button on a phone (not exactly but similar). In your case, it seems like you would want to stop the listener when user swipes away the app (which is the right thing to do) and you can achieve that by listening to, say, onPause() in your activity and remove the listener and re-register that in onResume() or so.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. What if I want to continue the listener even when user swipes away the app(kind of background way of using) and once he again opens the app, he should see the current session( stop button is present to stop). New session should only be opened when the user stops the listener, swipes away the app and opens it again. Is this possible? Also when does an app in watch gets killed? After sometime we swipe away the app? Could you please help?

Comment: App will be killed by system based on the available resources, etc as is the Android's usual. Based on the nature of your app, it doesn't seem to be wise to have it running in background; for one, you never know when framework is going to kill your app so your users will be surprised when that happens. Also, you should be very mindful of the battery required for your process so stop your listener when you leave the app.